# Thread execution output

Tags: java, multithreading

For the given code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    };

    Thread t1 = new Thread(r, "One ");
    t1.start();
    t1.sleep(2000);

    Thread t2 = new Thread(r, "Two ");
    t2.start();
    t2.sleep(1000);

    System.out.print("Main ");
}
```

The output is always coming as "One" "Two" "Main". Why is such behavior with threads in this code? Why always "t1" is starting first and not "t2" or main thread for that matter?

Comment: `t1` starts before `t2` because you call `t1.start()` before `t2.start()`

Comment: In my case, it is `Main One Two `  and which is nearly expected

Comment: @AmitBera this is the correct output. I have no idea how OP has Main printed as last.

Comment: As per his code `Main` never can be printed at last it will be always first.

Comment: Note also that `t1.sleep(2000)` and `t2.sleep(1000)` are very misleading, as written. `Thread.sleep(...)` is a *static* method which causes the *current* thread to sleep. So both calls pause the current (main) thread, not `t1` and `t2`.

Comment: Edited the code correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Thread.sleep()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) is a *static* method which pauses the *current* thread. The "current" thread here means the "thread from which the `sleep()` call was invoked": in this code that is *always* the main thread.

So your code is equivalent to, and should be written as

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    };

    Thread t1 = new Thread(r, "One ");
    t1.start();
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    Thread t2 = new Thread(r, "Two ");
    t2.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    System.out.print("Main ");
}
```

What happens is that you start `t1`, pause the **main** thread for two seconds, then start `t2`, pause the **main** thread for another second, and then print `"Main "` to the console.

Technically, there is no guarantee as to how long it will be between calling `t1.start()` and `System.out.println("One ")` (from `t1`'s runnable), and there is no guarantee as to how long it will be between calling `t2.start()` and `System.out.println("Two ")`. For all practical purposes, though, these will be at most of the order of milliseconds.

However, you are guaranteed that there will be at least two seconds between calling `t1.start()` and `t2.start()`, and that there will be at least one second between calling `t2.start()` and `System.out.println("Main ")`.

So for all practical purposes, you will print `"One "` to the console, then two seconds (plus or minus a few milliseconds, at most) later print `"Two "` to the console, then another second (plus or minus a few milliseconds) later print `"Main "`.

Any good (and reasonably configured) IDE will warn you when you refer to a static method via an object reference, as you do with `t1.sleep(2000)`, etc. You should not ignore these warnings and should correct the code, so that it is clearer what you are doing.

Comment: I didnt understand one point here. So if t1 is started and lets assume it is the running thread so calling sleep now should pause t1 or t2 for that matter depending on how the scheduler make them run. If they go to sleep state then there is a possibility for main thread to run print "main" before t1 or t2.

Comment: @Abhilash28Abhi No: that's the whole point. Calling `sleep()` pauses the *current* thread - the thread from which `sleep()` is called. So in both cases you pause the *main* thread. You never pause `t1`, or `t2`.

Comment: There is also a possibility that t1 can go to running state when we call t1.start(). So, then calling sleep() should put t1 to sleep being the current thread.

Comment: @Abhilash28Abhi Again, no. Calling `sleep()` does not, ever, put `t1` to sleep. It puts the *thread from which `sleep()` was called* to sleep. You are calling `sleep()` *from the main thread*, so it *always* puts the main thread to sleep.

Comment: Yes, i got your point. If i put the sleep() in the run() then "main" get printed first followed by "one" and "two".

Answer (score 0):

here we have total three threads *main*, *t1*, *t2*. when execution starts all the threads in pool are executing in asynchronously, because threads of the same priority are given equal treatment by the java scheduler and, therefore they run on a **first-come, first-serve basis**.

use `threadname.setPriority(intNum)` method to assign priority, which affects the order of running threads.

Comment: No matter the priority, you'll still see the same output unless you have something really weird in the scheduler. No scheduler is going to leave a running thread idle for a whole second.